# Problem Django on IIS 7.5 - PyISAPIe Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'

Tags: python, django, iis

I have some problem when I run the Django App on IIS 7.5..

Just follow the steps introduced by [this][1]. 
I successful run the project on IIS 7.5.

But, it show some problems.. like this..

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/


Traceback:
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  158.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  170.             raise ViewDoesNotExist("Tried %s in module %s. Error was: %s" % (func_name, mod_name, str(e)))

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: Tried home in module core.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

Comment: It looks like you're following some steps on another page, and have attempted to put a link to them.  Unfortunately, it seems you've omitted that link, and as a result the text '[this][1]' appears.  Can you please provide that link?

Comment: did you use this link https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer